# extremisation of proper time along geodesics in GR

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, geodesics

The geodesic equation can be derived by the variational principle in an arbitrary gravitational field (with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$). The path along such a geodesic extremizes the proper time $\tau$.

What I don't understand is, that for the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ we have maximal proper time $\tau$ along a geodesic, but for a general metric $\tau$ is "only" extremal (minimum or maximum or saddle point). Is there a physical intuition/argument for these different cases? Shouldn't $\tau$ also be maximized?

Comment: Are you only interested in timelike geodesics, not null or spacelike geodesics? To take away some of the mystery, compare with the principle of extremal time in geometric optics, and think about emitting light from the center of an ellipsoidal mirror. Rays that go out and back along the long axis have maximal time, while the short axis gives minimal time.